# manage drupal admin login and adfs login

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, admin, adfs

I have integrated ADFS login with Oauth2 client for my drupal web app.I have redirect uri 'http://mysite/users' . While entering this login it will redirect to adfs login so I can login as adfs user.how can I login with admin user and manage admin panel.I have used

Answer (score 1):

After drupal login, check the user role and if it is admin bypass the other login.

Comment: I have redirected to ADFS login page which has mailID and password.